# CUDA Array set to 0 after kernel call

Tags: arrays, cuda, ubuntu-14.04

I have a simple program with 3 array, that count how much the third array is 0 and the first and second has same values. when it's true increment another array index.
The problems are:

1. If kernel has only the first `if() then` function the array A is ever 0
2. If I insert `if() then else` function  the values of array A is set to 0 after index = 2  and don't count the state when A,B,C=0

this is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>

// Kernel that executes on the CUDA device
__global__ void square_array(float *a, float *b, float *c, float *res)
{
    int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    if (a[idx]=b[idx] && c[idx]==0) {
        res[0]++;
    }
    else if (a[idx]=b[idx] && c[idx]==1){
        res[1]++;
    }

}

// main routine that executes on the host
int main(void)
{
    float  *a_h, *a_d;  // Pointer to host & device arrays
    float  *b_h, *b_d;  // Pointer to host & device arrays
    float  *c_h, *c_d;  // Pointer to host & device arrays
    float  *res_h, *res_d;  // Pointer to host & device arrays

    const int N = 10;  // Number of elements in arrays
    size_t size = N * sizeof(float);
    //size_t size_s = 4 * sizeof(float);
    a_h = (float *)malloc(size);        // Allocate array on host
    cudaMalloc((void **) &a_d, size);   // Allocate array on device
    b_h = (float *)malloc(size);        // Allocate array on host
    cudaMalloc((void **) &b_d, size);   // Allocate array on device
    c_h = (float *)malloc(size);        // Allocate array on host
    cudaMalloc((void **) &c_d, size);   // Allocate array on device
    res_h = (float *)malloc(size);        // Allocate array on host
    cudaMalloc((void **) &res_d, size);   // Allocate array on device

    // Initialize host array and copy it to CUDA device
    //  for (int i=0; i<N; i++) a_h[i] = (float)i;
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) a_h[i] = (float)i;
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) b_h[i] = (float)i;
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) c_h[i] = (float)i;
    for (int i=0; i<4; i++) res_h[i] = 0;


    cudaMemcpy(a_d, a_h, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(b_d, b_h, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(c_d, c_h, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(res_d, res_h, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    // Do calculation on device:
    int block_size = 8;
    int n_blocks = N/block_size + (N%block_size == 0 ? 0:1);
    square_array <<< n_blocks, block_size >>> (a_d, b_d, c_d, res_d);
    // Retrieve result from device and store it in host array
    cudaMemcpy(a_h, a_d, sizeof(float)*N, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaMemcpy(b_h, b_d, sizeof(float)*N, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaMemcpy(c_h, c_d, sizeof(float)*N, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaMemcpy(res_h, res_d, sizeof(float)*N, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    // Print results
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++){
        printf("%f A \n", a_h[i]);
    }
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++){
            printf("%f B \n", b_h[i]);
        }
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++){
            printf("%f C \n", c_h[i]);
        }
    for (int i=0; i<4; i++){
        printf("%f res \n", res_h[i]);
    }

    // Cleanup
    free(a_h); cudaFree(a_d);
    free(b_h); cudaFree(b_d);
    free(c_h); cudaFree(c_d);
    free(res_h); cudaFree(res_d);
}
```

Comment: From a first glance, it seems like you are writing to `res[0]` and `res[1]` with **all** threads. The final values in this array will be rather arbitrary. *If* I understood you correctly, you could use some sort of reduction here, but it is far from trivial to implement this on the GPU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from the `=` in `if (a[idx]=b[idx] && c[idx]==0) {` that should be `==` as you already found (and same goes for the following `if` statement), there are at least two other issues in your code:

1. You don't check that the thread index doesn't go over the limit of the arrays. So since you are using 2 block of 8 threads, you have 16 threads accessing 10 elements arrays. To avoid the issue, you need to pass N as parameter for your kernel and add a `if ( idx < N )` somewhere.
2. You accumulate in `res` in parallel without any sort of protection, leading to all kinds of race conditions. This is a very typical histogram issue that is explained aplenty in the literature (web, books, CUDA examples...). A quick fix for you (albeit probably not the most effective one) would be to use atomic operations, such as `atomicAdd`. In you case, the line `res[0]++;` would become `atomicAdd( &res[0], 1 );`, and `res[1]++;` would become (as you guessed) `atomicAdd( &res[1], 1 );`. The support of this for float implies you compile your code while using compute capability at least 2.0.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I solved the problem.It was a mistake typing control = and not true ==